# is software updater application in ubuntu like sudo apt-get update?

Tags: command-line, updates

Does software update application in ubuntu 14.04 like sudo apt-get update command?

Comment: Yes it is called "Software Updater". type in dash and launch it.

Comment: @ThomasW. Are you sure this is a duplicate? I think the OP is asking more if the software center uses apt-get update vs what apt-get update actually *does*. It is possible he doesn't know either, but I think (with your answer below) this might be worth leaving.

Comment: Yes. Mr Seth what you said is correct. I know what apt-get update actually does, and I wanted to know if software center uses same command or similar. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Software Update application is just a GUI frontend to the `apt` and `dpkg` backends in the command line, which actually maintain and manage the packages.

The ultimate underlying commands being run are about equivalent to `sudo apt-get update` when you hit "Refresh" or "Check for Updates".  The about-equivalent command being run when you have all the packages selected in the graphical list of packages is `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, or for specific packages selected and others not selected, `sudo apt-get install PACKAGE1 PACKAGE2 PACKAGE3 ...` (where `PACKAGE#` is just a placeholder for selected packages).

Ultimately, `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, and the Software Update application are just different interfaces to the same goal - the updating of packages in the system, ultimately handled by `dpkg` in the end.